# Why is =AVERAGE returning a divide by zero error in this scenario?

Tags: google-sheets

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qW5rWJVUBQrliAJ0EsVShpk3mEwQwbLjZmpp9rcKgGU/edit?usp=sharing)

I get a divide by zero error when trying to =AVERAGE the output of a =SUBSTITUTE function in two cells.  When I don't use the =SUBSTITUTE function, but instead enter the desired result manually, I don't get the error.  I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `SUBSTITUTE` transforms number to string or text.

To convert it back to number, You could use any of the below methods:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C2,"%","")*1
```

- Just multiply(or divide) by 1 as shown above:  `*1`
- Add(or `-`) a zero:  `+0`
- Use a Double unary operator:  `--`
  (For Ex: `--SUBSTITUTE(...)`)